# wget cron job doesn't work but when manually refreshing script it works

Tags: php, cron, wget

My wget cron job looks like this (set to every minute for testing):

```
* * * * * wget -q -O - web-url.com/sub-folder/cron_job.php?us=user&pa=user2
```

It sends me email with html from php every minute as notification that cron is done, but php should send email to user and echo id of that user for testing. Now when cron job does it php is not executed (mail not sent and there is no id in mail that i get in cron sent info)
But when i go to that page then everything works, user gets mail and I see his id.
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to place quotes around the url. :) Otherwise it's probably not doing the get parameters.